# Switch case is printing only default value

Tags: c++, switch-statement

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int n;
//only printing the default value
cout<<"Press 1 for Hindi, Press 2 for English, Press 3 for Punjabi,   ess 4 for Japanese."<<endl;
cin>>n;
switch (n)
{ 
case '1':
cout<<"Namaste";
    break;
case '2':
cout<<"Hello";
break;
case '3':
cout<<"Sat Shri Akal";
case '4':
cout<<"Ohaio gosaimas";
break;
default:
cout<<"I am still learing more!!!";
}
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n` is an `int`, but your `switch` cases are `char`s. Make them consistent, i.e. either make `n` a `char`, or make the switch cases ints.

Comment: `case '1':` -> `case 1:` and so on. The value of '`1'` depends on the character encoding on your platform. Interestingly it is *not allowed* by the C++ standard to be 1.

Comment: @Bathsheba Wait, really? I was unaware of that constraint. Why is that? Or rather, what's the rule?

Comment: @cigien: 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 must be consecutive in any encoding. `'0'` cannot be 0 since the latter is the NUL terminator - used to signal the end of a C-style string. It follows therefore that `'1'` cannot be 1.

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that `n` is an integer type but in the switch statemen, your comparing it against `char`s.

You can use either of these two options to fix it,

1. Change `n` to be a char type.
2. Change the comparation to be an integer type.

For option 1, its a simple change.

```cpp
char n;
```

For option two, change the `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, ... to `1`, `2`, `3`, ...

```cpp
switch (n) {
case 1:
    ...
    break;
case 2: 
    ...
    break;
...
}
```

Make sure you don't mix up integers and characters specially when comparing!

Comment: This answer is essentially correct, but note that `char` is an integer type, just as `n` is. The underlying issue here is that the stream extractors for `int` and `char` do different things with the input.